# xsd file not build into jar when use IDEA

Tags: java

I define a xsd file in a package(under src/main/java) in maven project. But when the jar is builded, I find the xsd file is missing, and it is working when I use Eclipse, something need to do when use the IDEA? Anybody who encountered the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your .xsd file under /src/main/resources instead.

Comment: thanks, Leemans, I had solved the problem, IDEA marks as the folder to many types, such as Sources,Tests(we can see them in Project Structure), your suggestion is a way to solve the problem, but I want to do it like the Spring(which also define the xsd file in package),  I use the maven so i define this :

Comment: <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**/*.properties</include>
     <include>**/*.xml</include>
     <include>**/*.xsd</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>